# Maximum likelihood of Bernoulli

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

[image]

But I can't get to the correct answer. This is what I did:

$$\log(p(X|\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^{d}(\log(\theta_i^{x_i}) + \log((1-\theta_i)^{1-x_i})) \\ = \sum_{i=1}^{d} (x_i \log(\theta_i) + (1-x_i) \log (1-\theta_i))$$

I look for the maximum, so:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log(p(X|\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^{d} \frac{x_i}{{\theta}_i} + \sum_{i=1}^{d} \frac{1-x_i}{1-\theta_i}$$

And:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{d} \frac{x_i}{{\hat{\theta}}_i} + \sum_{i=1}^{d} \frac{1-x_i}{1-\hat{\theta}_i} = 0$$

But when I solve that I can't get the correct answer.

Comment: I may not understand the question exactly: should $\theta$ be a fixed scalar for all the $x_i$ or should it really be $\theta_i$? In other words, should your final MLE be a scalar or a vector?

Comment: $\theta_i$ is a scalar, because $\theta = [\theta_1 \ \  \cdots \ \ \theta_d]^T$ is a vector

Comment: I understand that, I'm talking about the estimation. At the top you have just a single number $\hat{\theta}$, not a vector. So it seems to me that you are trying to find the MLE among parameter vectors of the form $\vec{\theta}=(\theta,\theta,\dots,\theta)$ (i.e. with a constant probability choice). This is as opposed to allowing for arbitrary parameter vectors (which seems, at least on a practical level, silly: a sample of size $d$ shouldn't be used to estimate $d$ independent parameters). Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: If I understand correctly then your equation could be written as $\frac{1}{\hat{\theta}} \sum_{i=1}^d x_i + \frac{1}{1-\hat{\theta}} \sum_{i=1}^d 1-x_i =0$.

Comment: If I do that, I arrive to: $$\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{d+1} \sum_{i=1}^{d} x_i$$

Comment: Well, that's almost right...it should've been $d$ instead of $d+1$ but  the rest is right.

Comment: In fact you just made some algebraic error, because that equation is indeed solved by the desired result. It might help to write it in a simpler form, something like $s/y-(d-s)/(1-y)=0$, then solve for $y$ (obtaining $s/d$). Note that earlier both of us had a small but important error: that $+$ should be a $-$ (don't forget your chain rule!)

Comment: The initial question from @Ian is exactly what I had trouble with.  Is there some context surrounding this question, or this section in the text, which explains why the parameter should have equal values for each element?

Answer (score 1):

For samples $\mathbf x_1, \mathbf x_2, \ldots, \mathbf x_n$, each of which is $d$-dimensional vector, likelihood function is equal to
$$
f(\theta; \mathbf x_1, \ldots, \mathbf x_n) = \prod_{k=1}^n\prod_{i=1}^d \theta_i^{\mathbf x_{k}(i)}(1-\theta_i)^{1-\mathbf x_{k}(i)}=\prod_{i=1}^d \theta_i^{\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf x_{k}(i)}(1-\theta_i)^{n-\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf x_{k}(i)},
$$
where $\mathbf x_{k}(i)$ is the $i$th coordinate of vector $\mathbf x_{k}$.

Log-likelihood function is equal to
$$
L(\theta; \mathbf x_1, \ldots, \mathbf x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^d \left(\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf x_{k}(i) \cdot\log(\theta_i)+\biggl(n-\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf x_{k}(i)\biggr)\cdot\log(1-\theta_i)\right).
$$
When differentiating with respect to $\theta_i$, all terms except that which containes $\theta_i$, disappear: for $i=1,\ldots,d$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i}L(\theta; \mathbf x_1, \ldots, \mathbf x_n) = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf x_{k}(i)}{\theta_i}-\frac{n-\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf x_{k}(i)}{1-\theta_i}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf x_{k}(i)-n\theta_i}{\theta_i(1-\theta_i)}.
$$
Please note that $\left(\log(1-x)\right)'=-\frac{1}{1-x}$.

For any $i$, MLE $\hat\theta_i$ is a solution of equation 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf x_{k}(i)-n\hat\theta_i =0, 
$$
$$
\hat\theta_i=\frac1n{\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf x_{k}(i)}
$$
We obtain MLE for vector $\theta$ as 
$$
\hat\theta=\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf x_{k}.
$$

Comment: Oh, were we to assume that we were given an array of $n$ $d$-dimensional sample vectors? I did not get that from the question, but it would make much more sense. It's a bit weird to do it that way though, because the independence structure of $P(x \mid \theta)$ combined with elementary general properties of the MLE means that you're really computing $d$ MLEs of samples of one-dimensional Bernoulli r.v.s (each of which can separately be computed more or less as discussed in the comments).

Comment: It is assumed in provided answer that one need to prove.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sample of size $n$ then the likelihood function is

$$L(\theta)=\prod_{k=1}^n \prod_{i=1}^d \theta_i^{x_{ik}}\cdot(1-\theta_i)^{1-{x_{ik}}} $$

Taking logs

$$\log\left(L(\theta) \right)=\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^d \left(x_{ik}\cdot \log(\theta_i)+(1-x_{ik})\cdot \log(1-\theta_i) \right)$$

Now we focus on $i=1$ to calculate the estimator for $\theta_1$. We can do that because the partial derivatives w.r.t. $\theta_i$ are all equal.

$\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_1}\left(\sum_\limits{k=1}^n \left(x_{1k}\cdot \log(\theta_1)+(1-x_{1k})\cdot \log(1-\theta_1) \right)\right)$

$$=\frac{1}{\hat\theta_1}\cdot \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}x_{1k}-\frac{1}{1-\hat\theta_1}\cdot \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (1-x_{1k})=0$$

$$(1-\hat\theta_1)\cdot \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}x_{1k}= \hat\theta_1\cdot  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (1-x_{1k})$$

After some steps it comes out that $\hat\theta_1=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_{1k}}{n}$

Thus $\hat\theta=(\hat \theta_1, \hat \theta_2, \hat \theta_3,\ldots,\hat \theta_d)^T=\frac1n\cdot \left( \sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_{1k},\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_{2k},\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_{3k}\ldots ,\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_{dk}\right)^T$ $=\frac1n\ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(x_{1k}, x_{2k}, x_{3k}\ldots , x_{dk}\right)^T=\frac1n\cdot \sum_\limits{k=1}^n\mathbf{X_k}$